# ¿Como saber el id de la fila en un tree dentro de un form en modo edición en Odoo?

Tags: odoo, tree

Es posible en modo edición en un form en odoo, teniendo un tree dentro, poder al elegir un elemento poder ejecutar alguna acción teniendo en cuenta ese elemento o el id, en modo lectura funciona, pero en modo edición no, con un botón en cada fila del tree.

```
 test_info = fields.Html(
        related='lab_test_id.informacion_examen',
    )
```

form:

```
...
<field name="test_info" readonly="1"/>
<notebook colspan="4">
                        <page string="Lab Requests">
                            <field name="appointment_lines">
                                <tree string="Lab Request" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="lab_test"/>
                                    <button name="show_test_information" string="View Info" type="object" icon="fa-info" context="{'line_id': active_id}"/>
                                    <field name="cost"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
                        <page name="Note" string="Note">
                            <field name="comment"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
```

...
En el campo test_info queremos mostrar una información dependiente de item seleccionado en modo edición en el tree

```
@api.onchange('appointment_lines')
    def _onchange_appointment_lines(self):
        if self.appointment_lines:
            self.lab_test_id = self.appointment_lines[-1].lab_test

  def show_test_information(self):
        active_id = self._context('line_id')
        self.test_info = self.test_id.informacion_examen
```

Comment: Me faltaba colocar este campo: lab_test_id = fields.Many2one(
        string='Test',
        comodel_name='lab.test',
        ondelete='restrict',
    )